# Unwrapping the inside of a barrel

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm trying to UV unwrap the inside of a barrel I made.

The problem is, when I select the inside of my barrel, and use the
*Mesh > UV Unwrap... > Cylinder Projection*, I get a weird unwrapped form. How can I solve this?

[image: Unwrapping the barrel inside]

Comment: You could also look at the options at the bottom left corner in the tool menu (Where you change settings when adding a cylinder for example) and select "Align to Object" from the Direction menu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cylinder Projection is based on the angle of the view.

Try switching to front (<kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>) or side view (<kbd>Numpad 3</kbd>), then unwrapping again:

[image]

Comment: It worked, [see my result](http://oi58.tinypic.com/53l5kx.jpg). Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3):

Blender's automatic UV unwrapping doesn't always work correctly. You can do it manually easily if you mark(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > Mark Seam) the top seam, the bottom seam and one seam down the middle:

[image]

Then unwrap (<kbd>U</kbd> > Unwrap):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the ideas above you may also try applying the *Location*, *Rotation* and *Scale* in *Object Mode* using Ctrl-A.

Not doing so will really screw up a lot of the various operations in Blender, this includes UV unwrapping.

Comment: Don't count on the order of the answers to stay constant. Refering to answers above yours will not work when your answer is voted to the top. :-)

Comment: yeah, I forgot about this.  Thanks.  I'll leave it the way it is so people will learn from my mistake.