# Texture is missing in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

Because I am pretty new to blender I watched the tutorial [Introduction to Texturing with Cycles in Blender](http://cgcookie.com/blender/2012/02/29/introduction-texturing-cycles-in-blender/) from BlenderCookie.com.

I loaded [this texture](http://www.cgtextures.com/texview.php?id=45790&PHPSESSID=hm52d6qkqbfs5mnelh7m1fhff0) onto a sphere but then in all views the texture is just some kind of blurry with no details.

[image]

Comment: I don't see any texture on the sphere at all.. Did you you UV unwrap and add the texture to the material?

Comment: @gandalf3 no i didn't UV unwrap (i really don't know what that is) I just added a texture to my sphere. In the tutorial that start at 9:25. That is what I did

Comment: The tutorial you linked explains your issue at 10:10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that your texture does not have any mapping defined.

To fix this, you can either *[UV unwrap](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6755/599)* your object, or use the [*Texture coordinates*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/input/texture_coordinate.html) node.

To UV unwrap a UV sphere, all you need to do is:

1. Select your sphere and enter *Edit Mode* (<kbd>Tab</kbd>)
2. Select all (<kbd>A</kbd>)
3. Press <kbd>U</kbd>*>Sphere projection* [while in side view](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6758/599).

For more info on UV unwrapping, see [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6755/how-to-properly-unwrap-my-mesh).

[image]

There are also ways to map images without UV unwrapping, such as *[Blended Box Mapping](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/textures/image.html#properties)*:

[image]

The *Mapping* node is used to scale up the texture.

Comment: Cool, that worked. But just that I really understand how it works: Is mapping therefore that the sphere knows where the texture is? And why did the budy in the tutorial didn't had to do this? Thanks a lot again!

Comment: @BlenderShark Yes, that's more or less it. And he did do it in the tutorial (he might have done it beforehand, but he said he UV unwrapped them at `10:20`).

Comment: Oh, ok I wasn't patient enough to continue watching because this problem really drove me crazy. So thanks a lot!