# Only showing world texture, not allowing to add texture to other objects

Tags: texturing

I am looking to add textures to other parts of this scene. However, every time I click texture it doesn't seem to change from the previous world texture, which I applied.

Here is a link to my [blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/30735).

Also do you know how can I make the pillars dirty and realistic? Just like in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vtO1s86HhRU (he changes it to dirty at 34 seconds)

Comment: Having a problem adding textures and wanting to make dirty pillars are two separate issues, I would suggest asking about dirty textures in a separate question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For the blender internal:**

You have to change the texture type. The button is in the texture panel of the properties window. It is highlighted in red in the image below. You will want it to me set to *Material Textures*, the second button. A object that can have a materiel must be selected. If everything is selected or nothing is selected that option will not be there.

[image: texture button]

**For Cycles:**

The texture must be added through the cycles material. The texture panel when using cycles behaves differently then in the blender internal. If there is a texture node in the selected materiel then the texture will display in the texture panel. 
[image: cycles texture]

Comment: Hello thanks for replying i dont seem to have that option below for some reason. i would show you but i dont know how to add screen shots

Comment: @AyoAdelagun do you have a object that can have a materiel selected? If everything is selected or nothing is selected that option will not be there.

Comment: Yeah i believe so, i have clicked the icon next to the texture icon and that seems to be able to change the colour now i am not sure how to add an image ground texture on top

Comment: ahhh thanks a lot i think i figured it out now, now to try and get it more realistic :)

Comment: Erm sorry to question again david i am slightly confused am i to use texture in the node format? or through that other way? do you mean it looks a bit more realistic through node format?

Comment: @AyoAdelagun are you using the *Blender Render* or *Cycles Render*?

Comment: yes i am using cylces render, i am trying to use sand texture for the sand but its just coming up as brown in colour without the sand texture

Comment: because you are using cycles, use the nodes. for your other problem look [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6827/texture-is-missing-in-cycles)