# Texture not rendering in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, uv

[image: the screen that appears in the rendered view]
I want to add a wood texture to this art mannequin. I have tried everything, I have Unwrapped the model plugged in a mapping node and messed about with the scale but I'm sure I have overlooked some basic element of applying the texture. All that appears when I render it or go into the rendered/material viewports is a orange/yellow color.

[image: The Texture I want to add]

Comment: you have two problems, first [Z fighting](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5441/2217) causing the black parts. Second your mesh is not UV unwrapped http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6827/2217.

Comment: A mix node with a factor of 0 is a bad thing... try changing it to something higher.