# Material Preview doesn't match render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I've created a wood floor material using an image texture node, I'm happy with how it is displayed in the material preview.

However when I apply the material to any object, in this case the 'wood_floor', the shader seems to only apply a single color to the object rather than the textured material I've created.

Here is the [blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/35199).

[image: workspace]

What is causing this effect and how can I get the material to apply to the entire floor object?

Comment: the file you uploaded does not have the image texture, please **pack** the image with the file. you can use ***File-.External Data->Pack All Into .blend***

Comment: thanks, I have fixed the blend file, thanks for having a look!

Comment: related [texture-is-missing-in-cycles](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6827/texture-is-missing-in-cycles)  and [texture-not-rendering-in-cycles](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26125/texture-not-rendering-in-cycles)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a texture but blender can't guess what coordinates to use for the texture mapping. To fix try this: In your wood floor object a texture coordinate node. Connect the object coordinates to the vector connector on your image texture node.

[image]

Comment: This is great, is there some kind of "scale" node I could add to change the size of each 'plank' of wood?

Comment: @Reustonium yes there is, under *Add > Vector > Mapping*. Put it between your texture coordinate and texture nodes.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise you type faster than me...

Answer (score 2):

You need to UV Unwrap your mesh. You can do this by going into *Edit Mode*, selecting all vertices, and pressing <kbd>U</kbd> *> Unwrap*. You do not need to change your material at all, UV Maps are applied to all image textures by default.

[image: unwrap Mesh]

For more in-depth explanation of the process go visit the [**wiki article**](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Textures/Mapping/UV/Unwrapping)