# How to adjust transparency of alpha channel on a png image, without completely making it vanish?

Tags: transparency

I don't know if I am making myself clear, but the logo should still be visible, but the background removed. Lastly, I would want to make the logo itself transparent, if possible, how do I accomplish this? [image]

Comment: This looks very similar to [this other question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32997/how-to-place-a-png-texture-with-transparency-over-a-material), I think its answer will probably help.

Comment: As the other question says you need to take the image data and the image alpha(transparency) and plug them into a Mix Shader as the factor for the mixing is the image Alpha you need something to go in the second input for the Mix Shader. For this use a Transparency Shader. It is one of those things that seems overly complex but when you get the hang of it will allow you to do some truly amazing things.

Comment: This is my node layout: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aor67FEekLdyhvhql7zpfbGMo0bWKg

Comment: I basically want to make the logo transparent, and it's background completely invisible. But if you knew, then your answer is obviously correct.