# Black text not showing on model (transparent PNG)

Tags: modeling, node-editor

This is probably a noob question.

I want to add a text texture to a model. I've made the image in GIMP, if I use WHITE for the text color, it appears properly, but if  I change the color of the text to black, it doesnt show up. Everything in the PNG image is transparent except for the text. (Also, I need to give the model a specific color, as in different colors for the buttons)

I'm using Blender 2.80 Beta with EEVEE as renderer. (version date is 2019-04-09)

[image: NOde setup][image: White Texture shows]

Comment: "*This is probably a noob question.*" Yes it is, an it has been asked quite a few times before https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32997/how-to-place-a-png-texture-with-transparency-over-a-material and

Comment: The information of the alpha channel (what you call "transparent") is not used as part of the shader's color. When you use an image node, only RGB information is available on the color (yellow) socket. You would need to connect the alpha output (gray) socket, so that the alpha channel information can be used as factor on a color mix node or on a mix shader node.