# How can I write something on an object?

Tags: modeling, animation, texturing

I've tried to use curve method and also have tried to add texture on it. But my ways didn't work or I did something wrong.

How can I write for example "Aceton Box" on this object ?

[image]

Comment: maybe this will help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material/46447#46447   and this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32997/how-to-place-a-png-texture-with-transparency-over-a-material

Answer (score 3):

Here's what you can do with the Curve modifier.

## For 2.7#

Add your desired text, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>  > *Text*, then press <kbd>Tab</kbd>  to go into edit mode and type in your new text, press Tab again to exit edit mode. Now move your cursor to the center of the bottle mesh you have.

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>  and choose cursor to selected. Now add in a circle (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>) under the *Curves*. Scale it to match the outside of your bottle. Now click back onto the text and convert it to a mesh <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>  choose convert to mesh.

Now go under the modifiers tab and choose the curve modifier, select the circle you just created as the *Object*. You will then have to rotate your text 90 on the x-axis and change the scale of the circle to -1. You may have to mess around with the scale a bit.

## For 2.8+

] Everything above will remain the same, though there is no <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> shortcut in Blender 2.8, you will have to either use <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>  to search for it or go under the *Object Tab -> Convert*.

[image]

You can also add a *Solidify* modifier to your text as well to help it stand out a little.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked :) I'm appreciate ^^