# How do I add a name on an object

Tags: uv-image-editor

I have a model of a spaceship and I would like to place a name on it. From what I know, I can't simply put text on it. What is the best simple way to do it? I have about 20 ships to name so this one would be the template for me. Thanks very much.

Comment: can you elaborate more on this? Are you trying to assign a name to the model in blender or, as the tag suggests, literally print the name onto the ship's texture?

Comment: I want to name the ship itself, so add a name on the texture. Thanks

Comment: maybe this will help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material?noredirect=1&lq=1   or this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32997/how-to-place-a-png-texture-with-transparency-over-a-material

Comment: Using decal machine, you could create all spaceship name in photoshop/krita/guimp/web... and create decals, you can have good renders like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a text object, turn it to mesh with <kbd>ALT+C</kbd> ,knife project it onto the ship and give material. But since you need to do it twenty times, with a different name each time I guess, you could use a macro/python script doing just this. **NB**. To knife project the right way your model must be in **ortho** view.

Comment: This is what I did. Text > 3D letters > mesh > Copy and paste it into the model project and attach it to the ship. As for macro/python, I have no idea how to do that. Would need to research and study how to do it so for now this adding a text object will have to do. Cheers!