# How to set material underneath a texture?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

I am have this image and I'm trying to set the black background color to match the rest of the extinguisher. I tried messing around with some settings like Emission and subsurface color, but that messes with the image. Any help with my personal project would be greatly appreciated. Thank you :) [image]

Comment: you'll probably find the answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material/46447#46447   or here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32997/how-to-place-a-png-texture-with-transparency-over-a-material

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add a transparent image on top of a material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material)

Answer (score 0):

Prepare the sticker image, give it a transparent background (*Alpha* 0%). Select the faces where you want the sticker to be displayed, unwrap them, give them a new material.

Prepare your node setting: Create an *Image Texture* and load your sticker picture, plug it in a *Diffuse* node. Mix this *Diffuse* with another *Diffuse* node that has your object background color (red in your case).

Plug the *Image Texture Alpha* output in the *Mix Shader Factor* input so that the sticker background appears transparent.

[image]