# I'm brand new to blender - how do I add a texture to a specifically shaped object

Tags: uv, image

I just started learning Blender yesterday (via blender guru's doughnut), so I'm pretty new to this, though I have some experience using Maya in college. That was a few years ago so I'm pretty rusty in all regards. I decided to try making something on my own now and I thought that the blockbuster sign would be fun to design.

I have the shape all finished, now I just need to slap the decal on there that says "Blockbuster" - and this is where I'm running into trouble. I'm sure this is absurdly easy but I can't figure out how to get this image onto my model. I've been searching for a video to find out how to do this for like an hour with no luck. If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be great!

[image]

Comment: you need your text as a PNG file with a transparent background (alpha = 0), then upload this image into an Image Texture node, and plug this node's alpha into the factor of a Mix Shader

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rng7AYfJk4Q. Hope this helps , uv mapping is a little hard for beginners but it's easy to do it once you get the hang of it.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32997/how-to-place-a-png-texture-with-transparency-over-a-material