# embossed metal text for packaging box

Tags: materials, node-editor

I am new to 3D software, trying to get this result by using material nodes. As you can see the result black glossy background, and gold metallic embossed text as the the image show. I am using Blender 2.83.[image]

My Node material Setup like this, as you can see my sample, the black background doesn't have glossy as much as the gold metallic text, how could i separate control those, and as u know the my image text is reversed, i don't know why that happens.[image]

Comment: maybe read these answer, and also put a bit of Bump on your text: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material/46447#46447 .. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32997/how-to-place-a-png-texture-with-transparency-over-a-material

Comment: Hello :). What have you tried so far and where *exactly* are you stuck?

Comment: I have created model, i stuck creating material, don't know how to use the image to make bump, the emboss effect, and the gold metallic effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I searched on internet and played around the nodes material.
[image]
This is how I achieved the embossed effect with Bump node, I still cannot master the concept but it just works.