# mixing Image texture on top of a procedural texture

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders, image, procedural

i want to add weathering/dirt to the leather armor on a model, but the leather texture is procedural, and i want to use a mostly transparent image texture so i can select where to apply the effect to add the dirt and whatnot, but i cant find out how without the image parts that are painted completely covering the procedural texture

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32997

Comment: its close but i need the image texture to add to the procedural one not completely cover it

Comment: That seems easy to achieve by changing the blend mode of the mix node. You can also manually soften the strength of the alpha channel with a math node