# I want to apply a logo image on a tea kettle which is sphere and I am not able to apply that in front of it

Tags: texturing

[image: this is going like this]

The logo is placed near the handle, but I want that my logo comes in front of the kettle. How do I do this?

Comment: see the answers here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32997/how-to-place-a-png-texture-with-transparency-over-a-material

Answer (score 1):

It appears you already have your Logo in your material, but it is applied in the wrong place, as I can see green near the handle.  One way you might have done this is by using an image node in your material:

[image: Simple logo with alpha applied as image.]

If that's the case, one way to fix this is in the UV Editor.  In this example, I have a sphere and have applied a logo, but, like yours, it's not where I want it.  In the UV Workspace, I can see the sphere:

[image: Sphere]

and I can see the UV Map of the sphere, showing the logo image:

[image: UV Map overlaying image]

One way to position the logo is to move the UV Map:

[image: UV Map moved]

resulting in the logo being "moved" to the front:

[image: logo in front]

Answer (score 0):

Example from scratch (with a sphere instead of a kettle, but the workflow is the same)

1. add a sphere and a plane like this

[image]

2. give the plane a image texture (your logo)

[image]

3. add shrinkwrap modifier to plane

[image]

4. choose target "sphere" (kettle)
5. now you see, that "nothing really happened" - this is because the plane has not enough geometry to "hug" the sphere correctly, so press <kbd>TAB</kbd> to enter edit mode, right click on plane and choose subdivide
6. enter 15 (or whatever value you want, the higher the value, the smoother your image/logo will be

[image]

7. increase the offset slightly so that you can see your image/logo perfectly

[image]