# How to layer textures

Tags: texturing, materials

I'm looking for a way to use two diffuse textures, but have them layered on top of each other.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is I have two head textures, one with eye outlines and one without, and I thought it'd be much easier is I made the outlines a separate layer and I could toggle them on or off with a driver perhaps.

Comment: Have you tried doing this with the shader editor? Using for example your two textures and mixing them with a mix shader or a mix RGB, then using a custom factor to merge them as you want

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32997/how-to-place-a-png-texture-with-transparency-over-a-material