# How do I use an image and lay it on another material to create an Dye Sublimation effect

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders, shader-nodes

How do I use an image or font to "layover" or "infuse" on to fabric material to achieve a dye sublimation effect [seen below]? The font I would like to turn into an image texture (maybe that is a different topic) but an image I would like to bring in as an image texture and have it lay on to a fabric so that the knit of the fabric would show through.

[image: dye sublimation]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32997/how-to-place-a-png-texture-with-transparency-over-a-material https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material