Can't export texture
I have a model of the cup with pretty easy textures, but there is one specific thing: I added a png on it's UV (and adding a png was a nightmare, I did not expect that simply applying png to existing material could cause so many problems.). So I tried to export it as fbx for unity project, but my png isn't exporting with other textures and I can't understand why. Could it be because of bad UV for png? And if it is, what should I do to make correct UV? When I making good UV it's absolutely disgusting in 3d view... 

there was a similar problem several days ago, is your image called something.png? or what is its name?

See how to put a use a png over a material https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32997/how-to-place-a-png-texture-with-transparency-over-a-material Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures for why it is not exporting
