# How do I straighten UV maps?

Tags: uv

How can I straighten ALL the vertical UV lines at once? Is there a hot keyshort cut? Or if I have to do them one by one .. is there at shortcut for that? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: A bit related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23293/uv-coordinates-on-a-deformed-plane

Comment: There's an addon for straightening UV maps - http://blenderaddonlist.blogspot.com/2015/05/addon-quad-unwrap.html. Didn't test it though, but may be useful.

Comment: And here is a paid add-on: https://cgcookiemarkets.com/all-products/uv-squares/

Comment: It's curved in the first place due to the angle of your view. If you view it straight on (press numpad 1) it should be straight. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6758/599

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The [UVSquares addon](https://github.com/Radivarig/UvSquares) is designed to do this easily. Select the uv's you want to straighten out and click a button.

[image]

Comment: Awesome! You just saved me so much work! Would you consider writing what the rest of the buttons do?

Comment: Is this a paid add-on?

Comment: It is released under GPL, you can download a free copy from github and if you think it is good enough and want to support the developer you can pay for a copy through CGCookieMarkets.

Answer (score 21):

There is no shortcut for that unfortunatelly.

You may do it using ***pinning*** and repeating the scaling of the edge loops with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> shortcut, although it isn't a fast method.
[image]

In *Uv Editor* select the corner of the UV island, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>-->*Cursor to  Selected*. Change the *pivot type* to ***2D Cursor***. Select the bottom edge of your island and press <kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>Y</kbd>,<kbd>0</kbd> to straighten it. Now press <kbd>P</kbd> to ***pin*** the selected vertices. Do the same with upper, left and right edges. Next, go to the *3D View* window and unwrap your mesh again. 
[image]

Now straighten the other edge loops using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> command. Change the *pivot type* to ***Median Point***, select the edge and scale it as described above. Then select another edge and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to repeat the scaling process.
[image]

Comment: Related answer that uses another method: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65565/straighten-the-series-of-vertices-in-uv-editor

Answer (score 2):

In Blender 2.8, you can also do it with the built-in addon MagicUV.

Here is a simple geometry I created.

[image]

The red lines are the marked seams. In the UV editor, you can see the original UV was not straighten.

All you need to do is select an end edge and press **N** > in **Magic UV Tab** > in **UV Manipulation** check **Align UV**  > check **Transmission** > hit **Straighten** or **XY-axis**.

[image]

And the line will be straighten.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not always applicable, but worth trying if your UV map is already nearly gridlike: Make a very tiny temporary image, with as many pixels as your mesh has columns, and enable snap to pixels, then select all your verts and drag them around. There will probably be some hand cleanup afterwards, though.