# Straightening out ALL uneven UVmap vertices in unison w/o overlapping?

Tags: uv

Instead of tediously straightening all the edges to align perfectly vertical one by one by one, is there some way to straighten out ALL the UVmap vertices ALL at once (like on the left side all nice nice vertical) without having them mashup and overlap into one --as with happens when I select them all and type S + X + 0?

[image]

Comment: how did you unwrap your object?

Comment: Cylinder projection - I tried almost every unwrapping option and that seemed to be the best, albeit still a little slanted as you can see.

Comment: try [uvsquares](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/41202/935)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just redo the UV unwrapping to get it straight.

Starting with a cylinder.

Select an edge.
[image]

Mark it as seam.

[image]

Select all faces.

[image]

Unwrap (no special projection, but a straight unwrap).

[image]

You should have a straight UV map like this:

[image]

Then just scale it to meet your needs.