# Straighten the series of vertices in UV editor

Tags: uv

I've got a bottle modeled and I want to put a Nuka-Cola label on it. I took where I want to put it, marked the seam, and unwrapped it. It looks like this:
 [image]
I want to straighten the UV so that it matches the angle of the Label, is there any way I can do this? I understand it will be a bit distorted, but i'll deal with that afterwards.

[Here's my project files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BzgDIjhDOu6EZkN3LUJfRFRPa3c?usp=sharing) (Not using Blend-Exchange because you need the images aswell)

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41132/how-do-i-straighten-uv-maps

Comment: What about using Mesh -> UV Unwrap -> Cylinder ? (You need to be in front + ortho : `5` + `1` )

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't want to straighten your UV islands ([How do I straighten UV maps?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41132/how-do-i-straighten-uv-maps)), cause in your case it might be very time consuming you might repeat the steps I've shown in the .gif below.
In *Edit Mode* select all faces (<kbd>A</kbd>), press <kbd>U</kbd>-->*Lightmap Pack*-->*OK*. Now select one of the face to make it active, then again press <kbd>U</kbd>-->*Follow Active Quads*-->*OK*. Your UV island is straight now. Adjust it using <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>S</kbd> to fit the image. If your mapped image is upside down just scale it negative 1 (<kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>Y</kbd>,-1).
[image]