# How to make UV mesh more regular?

Tags: mesh, uv, transforms

I'd like to turn mesh like top one into somethine like bottom one. Is there any better way to do that than selecting edge loops and scaling them vertically/horizontally to 0? Something more automatic

[image]

Comment: I found that you can press [W] and choose align X/Y. But it still requires doing that per loop. It's just slightly faster because [W] is close to [alt] so you can do it without moving hand. [0] was quite far so required hand movement.

Comment: You could select a loop, straighten it and then use `Shift`+`R` to repeat last action (could be a faster way). See also http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41132/how-do-i-straighten-uv-maps