# Polygon hair in blender using bezier curves

Tags: hair, bezier-curves

In the attached image you'll see a hair model made by Apachii (http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/10168/?) -a Skyrim modder. I downloaded all her hair files and have tried to reverse engineer her hair technique. It's extremely hard to replicate in Blender and I've probably seen every tutorial on the subject.

[image]

I suspect the best approach would be to use bezier curves and then convert the curves to a mesh. I have two problems with this:

1. how did she get the curves to lie so closely to one another without overlapping? Is there a way to snap bezier curves together so they hover above each at a set distance and never overlap?
2. how did she unwrap all those bezier curves so beautifully (see image below).

[image]

Here is a clearer image of the sort of hair technique I'm trying to master:

[image]

Comment: If you look closely they do overlap at times, overlapping should not be a big problem. My guess is that it is just done by hand, with lots of work and patience, I don't think there are many shortcuts

Comment: There are many good tutorials about creating polygon hair in Blender on youtube. The magic formula is always the same: patience and practice ;-) 
Take a look at this one (and don't get turned off by the pink theme; it's actually very good): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z_Zj2H0UEes

Comment: CGCookie has a [tutorial using curves](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nn7mISvVzJk) to create hair. I doubt the last example you show used curves. [This](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/41202/935) can help with uv's.

Comment: Here's another link to a dev tutorial by s.o. who worked on "Rise of the Tomb Raider": http://tombraider.tumblr.com/post/131320726110/dev-blog-creating-believable-hair-and-fur

Comment: Thanks guys! Time and patience it is. I found those two tutorials before, but I didn't  think I could get results like the first image using those techniques. I'll give it another crack :) The UVSquares addon is useful, but in this case it didn't make all the hair strands the same size like in the above photo. Maybe it's a max or maya thing?

Comment: If you want the UV scaling to stay accurate you can select all the objects and do average UV scaling and hit pack island. That’s what I do