# How can I get a straight UV map when I unwrap?

Tags: uv

I modelled this little wall in Blender and I dont know how to get the curve straight.
Can somebody help?

http://prntscr.com/g2ljc6

I changed a few things with my model and Im not sure how to get the x-scale of the selceted faces of the UV exactly like the x-scale of the faces underneath...

Does somebody know how to fix this?

[image]
[Screenshot](http://prntscr.com/g2ljc6)

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure about what you ask, but if you wish to have the UV map straight, even if the mesh is curve, try the "follow active quad" unwrap option.

Comment: [This question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/41132/935) also offers some options. You could even use the [built-in UV align tools](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/uv_image/uv_editing/layout_editing.html#align).

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do this, if you don't want to unwrap again, is to select and scale the edges. Select the top edge of your curve like this:
[image]

Then press:

1. <kbd>S</kbd>
2. <kbd>Y</kbd>
3. <kbd>0</kbd>

The scaling result: (Repeat for the bottom edge)
[image]

Lastly scale the bottom edge along the X axis. The final result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your UV map, straighten out the coordinates of your curve so they form a straight line. When you texture a line on top of the straight, it will get bent with the curve of your mesh. Remember, textures on a UV map will behave like you make it.

Put a line on a curve, and you get a line on your curve. But but a line on a straight, you will get a bent line on your curve. UVs are simply coordinates; Which pixels will go where.

Screenshot of what I'm talking about;
[image]