# What is the best solution for this UV problem?

Tags: texturing, uv

I am following tutorial for an AKM and I am having trouble straightening these faces. The reason I am asking this is because the modeling and UV parts are done in 3DS MAX and I use Blender. So far, I have been able to follow along but this part is giving me some trouble. I want to straighten them because I want the texture to follow the shape of the magazine but I don't know how to do that.

I am still learning how to use TexTools and UV Squares and the Rectify option does not work, as you can see in the first image.

What is the best solution for this problem? Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My proposed solution:

1. Map the item as it is. The UV-map is bent.
2. In the UV-editor, manually straighten the outer edges. Using <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> or <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> for instance.
3. Select the outer edges and pin them. Toggle pinning with <kbd>P</kbd>.
4. Go back to the 3D editor and do the UV-mapping again.

The pinned vertices should stay as they were and the inside should be remapped to follow.

[image]

When you pin a vertex in the UV-editor, it is marked with a red border.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are 3 solutions:

- You build a straight (not curvy) magazine, you UV map it, then you bend its mesh in *Edit* mode... the map will follow the shape.
- You use the *UVSquares* addon as explained here: [How do I straighten UV maps?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41132/how-do-i-straighten-uv-maps)
  the addon is available here: https://github.com/Radivarig/UvSquares
- You could also select each edge and align its vertices with <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> or <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>, depending on the axis, but it's a little bit tedious if you have a lot of edges.

You say that you've tried the *UVSquares* addon, but the top and bottom of your mesh are very messy, the addon can't find out how to straighten that, so I don't think you can conclude anything about this method:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried those solutions but they are not satisfactory. I am not making another magazine because I have to learn how to do this. You can see the results of UVSquares in the first image. As for the third solution, there are indeed a lot of edges so it is not viable. There has to be a better way.

Comment: yes, the result is bad because the top and bottom of your mesh are very messy!

Comment: How is it very messy? I followed the Ultimate Weapon tutorial for 3DS Max to the letter. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9MYGCdf9VHs

Comment: look at the detail I've posted, how can the addon guess how to make straight lines and perpendicular ones when it comes to these edges?

Comment: I don't know. I am still learning. I did what the instructor did. Anyway, I think I have found a solution but it involves a lot of manual work. Basically, I only took the faces in the middle and used UV Square. I then repositioned and rescaled the other parts of the x axis and now I have to do some manual work to straighten and stitch them back together. What do you think? https://imgur.com/MdexLvU

Comment: I think you should try to improve the topology, I'm not sure what he's done is the best one, and a good topology would precisely prevent all these kind of problems. Perhaps try to work more on modeling, and when you'll be familiar with it, then learn materials + UV mapping, etc...